# Python Wacom Interface

Tags: python, driver, hid, wacom

I am trying to write a python script on Windows 7 to interact with my Wacom Bamboo Pen tablet. Wacom recommends using the WinTab API, and it works fine, but not for my application. I don't want the Wacom tablet to act as a pointing device (as in, it should not move the cursor). All I want is raw x, y data from the device.

What is the best way to implement this? Do I have to write a different driver for the tablet to allow this? Or can I modify the existing Wacom driver to not affect the system cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in wintab you can get the raw coordinates. At least in [Python wrapper for wintab](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/wintab.html#) you can access them:

```
cgkit.wintab.Packet.x
```

> In absolute mode, contains the scaled
>   cursor location along the x axis. In
>   relative mode, contains the scaled
>   change in cursor position.

```
cgkit.wintab.Packet.y
```

> In absolute mode, contains the scaled
>   cursor location along the y axis. In
>   relative mode, contains the scaled
>   change in cursor position.

I'm [investigating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978835/is-there-an-api-for-python-to-work-with-pressure-sensitive-pen-tablets) for myself if there is an cross-platform api for tablets, but if you need windows-only solution that should work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you have to use Python Computer Graphics Kit **cgkit**.
If you don't want to build it from source and don't mind using older version of Python you can use the binaries.

The version tested in Windows works with Python 3.2 32-bit.
Download and install Python from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2/python-3.2.msi)
Then download and install Python Computer Graphics Kit from [here](https://netactuate.dl.sourceforge.net/project/cgkit/cgkit/cgkit-2.0.0/cgkit-2.0.0.win32-py3.2.exe)

Test if Wintab driver is available by running the following 2 lines

```
from cgkit import wintab
print(wintab.available())
```

If you get **False** then you have to install the drivers.
You can download the drivers from [here](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/gqgt01ww.exe)

Restart the computer after installing the drivers and try the 2 lines again you should get **True**.

Now to retrieve stylus data refer to [Python wrapper for wintab](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/wintab.html#)