# is there an API for python to work with pressure-sensitive pen-tablets? (Mac OS, Linux)

Tags: python, wxpython, tablet, pen-tablet

I want to write a cross-platform wxPython app, and I'm wondering if there a single API to work with pen-tablets on different platforms? I'm only interested to get pressure value and ereaser flag - but I couldn't fined anything cross-platform for python.

**UPD.** so far, I found only windows-specific [solution](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/wintab.html#), what are the options for Mac OS and Linux?

Comment: Possible duplication of question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848694/python-wacom-interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848694/python-wacom-interface)?

Answer (score 2):

https://bitbucket.org/AnomalousUnderdog/pythonmactabletlib

> A small Python library to allow Python scripts to access pen tablet
>   input data in Mac OS X.
>
> The library exists as plain C code compiled as a dynamic
>   library/shared object. It interfaces with the Mac OS X's API to get
>   data on pen tablet input.
>
> Then, Python scripts can use ctypes to get the data.

Send me a message if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

If your target tablets are HIDs, which they probably are, you can use [python-hid](http://dir.filewatcher.com/d/Debian/i386/python/python-hid_0.2.15-1_i386.deb.38734.html).